# raster to point conversion using python

Tags: python, arcgis, raster

I want to use a python script to convert several raster files to point files, based on the Value field in the raster.  However, I want to exclude the cells with "0" value.  Is there a way to do this in one step or do I need to copy the original rasters to new rasters and set the no_data value to 0?  Any recommendations?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you details more the format of the raster file and the one of the "point file" you want? For instance, is the point file a csv file with columns (latitude, longitude, value)?  It will help people here to determine the best solution

Comment: The raster file is a single band GRID raster.  The point file needs to be a simple point shapefile.

Comment: Did you have already some python code to import and export the data? I think it would be helpful to include it in the question... also maybe you will have better chance on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: *I'm the author of the following library.*

You can try [lidario.Translator](https://lidario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/translator.html): It allows to quickly convert several .tif files into point clouds of any type (np.array, pd.dataframe, csv file, ...). It works with GDAL under the hood.

**Geotiff to np.array:**

```
import lidario as lio
    
# Create a Translator object which will take a tif file and return a np.array
translator = lio.Translator("geotiff", "np")
    
# Translate the tif file and get the np.array
point_cloud = translator.translate("/path/to/file.tif", no_data=0, band=1)
```

Save to CSV directly:

```
import lidario as lio

translator = lio.Translator("geotiff", "csv")
translator.translate("/path/to/file.tif", out_file='output.csv', no_data=0, band=1)
```

Comment: You *must disclose affiliation in the post* when linking to something you're affiliated with. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)